# JMX authentication access from JConsole

Tags: java, authentication, jmx

I have setup a Java application to start with JMX enabled

```
-Djavax.management.builder.initial= -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
```

I have also setup the properties files necessary

java/jre/lib/management/management.properties

```
com.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999
com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true
com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

jmxremote.access

```
monitorRole readonly
controlRole readwrite
```

jmxremote.password

```
monitorRole QED
controlRole R&D
```

After I start the application and try to connect

```
jconsole localhost:9999
```

I get the message:  Connection failed: Connection refused: connect
When I try again, entering the credentials monitorRole:QED, it gives the same message.

If I repeat the steps above, but with authentication turned off, I can connect fine.

```
com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

What is causing authentication to refuse my connections?

Comment: enable debug option and check

Comment: Double check the username and password

Answer (score 0):

What is likely the cause is that your password file is not read protected. It needs to made such that only the user is able to read its contents. One could achieve this using:

`chmod 600 pwd.file.name`

or in your case

`chmod 600 jmxremote.access`

You should actually be able to see this error printed to the command line if you try and run your application with a file that is not read protected and

`com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true`

Note however that in some cases when sending the password file to a remote location (such as pushing to a git remote) the access rights you have assigned it may be reset and thus you may to have to set them remotely.